# How can i delete the Current position from RecyclerView (Firebase Database)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Here is my Adapter Code :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    SlideshowModel slideshowModel = slideshowModelList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.notification).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholders).into(holder.image);
    holder.title.setText(slideshowModel.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(slideshowModel.getDesc());
    holder.date.setText(slideshowModel.getDate());

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications");


        }
    });
}
```

I have got the Reference to the Node of the Database as "notifications".

Also the recyclerView has multiple items. How can i delete the current position on clicking on delete button in the Adapter ?

Comment: Do you have in your `SlideshowModel` class an `id` property that holds as a value the key of your object? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specifying the data structure you're using. So I am assuming that you have `notificationId` the child key in your `SlideshowModel` model.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications").child(slideshowModel.notificationId);

databaseReference.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,@NonNull  DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError == null) {
                    //failed to delete
                } else {
                    //deleted successfully
                }
            }
        });
```

For more details, you can check the [link](https://medium.com/@kodagvikram/firebase-real-time-data-read-write-best-practices-android-67a06fa6420d)